# Decrypting data for use with SQL Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql, reporting, service

I have recently started to look at sql reporting services. 
I have data stored in a database which has been encrypted with an AES cypher before being stored away.

I've had a look at building some reports using Microsoft Report Builder 2.0 and it seems quite nice and simple for knocking together some simple reports.

My question is: Can I decrypt this data before displaying it on a report? Is there anyway to run code with these reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RDLC (C is for Client), and then look at the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms and Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms namespaces.

This allows you to use code to generate your data, for example get your data from SQL Server then decrypt it as required before presenting it to the ReportViewer control.